# Is there something like the Poynting vector for hydraulic circuits?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, electricity, fluid-dynamics, poynting-vector

The [Poynting vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting_vector) is a representation of the [energy flux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_flux) in electromagnetics, showing the amount and direction of power flow at different points in space.  In electric circuits, the energy is not carried inside the wires (meaning the vector is just 0 inside them?), but by the electric and magnetic fields surrounding the wires.  The DC circuit is the simplest case:

[image]

- [Understanding Electricity and Circuits: What the Text Books Don’t Tell You](http://sydney.edu.au/science/uniserve_science/school/curric/stage6/phys/stw2002/sefton.pdf)
- [IN A SIMPLE CIRCUIT, WHERE DOES THE ENERGY FLOW?](http://amasci.com/elect/poynt/poynt.html)

Is there an equivalent concept of energy flux for an equivalent hydraulic circuit?

[image]

Does the energy flow inside the pipes in this case?  I'm guessing the energy flux has some kind of parabolic profile inside the pipes proportional to the flow rate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is such a diagram--- it is the flux of energy in the linearized gravitational field (if you use full GR, you get complications with defining the energy). Unlike the electromagnetic case, where the electric field carry the bulk of the energy and the momentum of the charge carriers is negligible, in the gravitational case, it is the opposite.

You can also imagine electromagnetic circuits in which you accelerate very massive spheres which are very lightly charged, and use these as current carriers, and in this case, the momentum of the current carriers will not be negligible.

EDIT: To clarify, there are gravitational fields created by moving water which surround the pipe, like the electric and magnetic fields surround the current-carrying wire. There is an energy flow in these gravitational fields, which carries energy, just like the Poynting flux does. These effects are negligible for ordinary materials at ordinary density. Nearly all the energy flux (all but the tiny negligible fraction in the gravitational field) is carried by the water in the pipe, but the momentum in the water is not analogous to the Poynting vector, it is analogous to the electron momentum, which also carries a small amount of energy in a current carrying wire.

Comment: Hmm..  Hydraulics don't require gravity to work, though.  I'm thinking of just a simple system of pipes with pistons.

Comment: @endolith--- the direct analog to electromagnetic fields carrying signals of the currents is the gravitational field carrying signals of bulk material flow. This field momentum surrounds the pipes and pistons, and looks similar qualitatively to the Poynting flux in a circuit. It can be ignored in real life, because the gravitational momentum is negligible.

Comment: Downvote? What is the issue with the answer? It is correct that the gravitational field Poynting-type vector are the direct analog for bulk mechanical flows and pressures of the Poynting vector in EM for bulk flow of charges.

Comment: I upvoted it.  The difference in momentum carried by the flowing particles sounds like the gist of what I'm asking.  I'm still not sure why gravity's involved, though.  Can you draw a diagram?  I added a diagram of the hydraulic analog I'm thinking of.

Comment: @Georg: The question asked for the mechanical analog of the Poynting vector. There is such an analog _only_ in the gravitational field, and in no other way. This is the proper answer--- there is no better one.

Comment: @endolith: The gravitational analogs of magnetic fields in General Relativity surrounds the pipe, and carry extra momentum through the space in a way very similar to the Poynting vector in EM. There is no other space-filling field which is made by hydrolic flows.

Comment: @RonMaimon: Sorry, I still don't understand.  Energy can flow in a hydraulic system regardless of whether it is driven by gravity or by a pump.  Since there are no fields created by the energy source,  I would imagine the energy flux exists only inside the pipes, but I don't understand this 100%.

Comment: @endolith: there are gravitational fields created by moving water which surround the pipe, like the electric and magnetic fields surround the current-carrying wire. There is an energy flow in these gravitational fields, which carries energy, just like the Poynting flux does. These effects are negligible for ordinary materials at ordinary density. Nearly all the energy flux (all but the tiny negligible fraction in the gravitational field) is carried by the water in the pipe, but this flow is not analogous to the Poynting vector, it is analogous to the electron momentum.

Comment: @RonMaimon: Ahhh, I see what you're saying now.  You're talking about the gravitational field *created by* the water's mass moving through the pipes, not the external gravitational field that moves water in a gravity-driven hydraulic system.  I think this is a good answer and I don't know why others are downvoting it.  Could you edit it to make this more clear?

Comment: Also, these different energy flows propagate at different speeds, don't they?  The gravitational waves travel at the speed of light, while the pressure waves travel at the speed of sound.  In electric circuits, the energy is mainly carried by EM waves, which travel at the speed of light in the dielectric, while a small amount is carried by the momentum of the electrons, which travels at a much lower drift velocity?  And an extremely negligible amount would be carried by gravitational waves in electric circuits, too?

Comment: @endolith: The momentum and energy in electric circuits is not carried by electromagnetic waves, but by a static electromagnetic field (not a wave). It is a stationary energy flow, which is set up at the speed of light when you first switch on the current. The gravitational system is exactly the same. There is a static momentum flow in the gravitational field which is set up quickly when you first start the flow, and it is there all the time, because it is a momentum flow in a static field.

Comment: @RonMaimon: Yes, I mean the initial energy onset takes time to travel from the source to the load.  In an electric circuit this speed is determined by the properties of the line connecting them, and is usually less than c.

Comment: I downvoted because the question was phrased in relatively basic terms, and was about a simple topic, but the answer was about GR. The relationship between something mundane and GR is interesting for sure, but it is unhelpful and rude to the asker to answer every question in the most complicated possible way.

Comment: To elaborate: If the question demonstrated an understanding of physics on a level that would imply at least *some* familiarity with GR, this would be a great answer. The value of an answer depends on the question. If somebody asks how an incandescent light bulb works, and the reply is given in terms of quantum electrodynamics, then the reply is probably useless to the questioner.

Comment: @ColinK: Well I asked the question and I think the answer is basically good.  It could be worded better, but making analogies between EM and gravity fields, and between the momentum of each particle is a good way to explain the difference.

Comment: @ColinK: I don't think GR is all that complicated, and this question was begging for a GR answer. It is condescending to assume that the questioner can't understand something as basic as "energy-momentum sources gravity". I don't respect the labels "elementary" and "advanced", because they are just warning labels to the public, "learn this" and "don't learn this". Any adult of sound mind can learn General Relativity, especially in the linear regime.