# From where energy is gained or given?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, energy-conservation, conservation-laws

for example suppose we have in a linear smooth surface and 2 persons A and B equal masses. A pushes the B so B gains a velocity $u$ and A gains velocity $-u$ but both have same kinetic energy. my question is the energy that A and B have is came from the chemical energy of body of A who pushed?

Comment: I don't understand the down-vote. It's a simple, but clean conceptual question. If it's a duplicate (I haven't looked) that's another matter, but the downvoter didn't flag as a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From where does the force/energy of action-reaction comes from? (Newton's Third Law of Motion)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/32147/from-where-does-the-force-energy-of-action-reaction-comes-from-newtons-third)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the physical interpretation of a muscle action is adenosine triphosphate (ATP) being turned into adenosine diphosphate (ADP) in the right location of an array of proteins such that the energy released can be turned into a force between body parts, which usually turns into motion.
(Exceptions in such cases as standing over a 4-foot wrecking ball and trying to lift it - forces are exerted, but nothing moves except except your sweat.)

Comment: And the ATP is created by various metabolic pathways from carbohydrates, fats or proteins, which are created by plants, or animals eating plants, that grow under sunlight, or grow lights powered by nuclear power plants, etc,  etc ...

Answer (score 0):

If person A does the pushing then person A does the work at the expense of chemical energy stored in person A.
It is no different to person A pushing a rock instead of person B.