# Three body force

Tags: three-body-problem

Reading on wikipedia about [Faddeev equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faddeev_equation), I've come across the notion of three-body force. The [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_force) which describes this type of force doesn't give me any understanding what it is about.

My questions are: does every three-body problem have such force? Or are e.g. classical celestial three-body problems free of it? If it's not in every three-body problem, then what classes of problems do have it?

Also, does such a force violate principle of superposition for forces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do however remember the following line from the link you yourself have cited:

**In general, if the behaviour of a system of more than two objects cannot be described by the two-body interactions between all possible pairs, as a first approximation, the deviation is mainly due to a three-body force.**

Hence, it can be seen that, initially, when people were thinking of many-body problems, they encountered terms in the mathematical formulation which they later termed as many body forces. Incidentally, they were discovered in strong interactions and were a result of gluon mediation. In the celestial scale hence, you would need to have a similar mediating phenomena/theory to explain any physically valid three body force.

Also related: [N-body forces in classical mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/81674/n-body-forces-in-classical-mechanics)