# Are fundamental forces always attractive/repulsive, i.e. parallel to the separation?

Tags: forces, vectors, interactions

If magnetic monopoles existed it would not be the case - the forces on an electron and a magnetic monopole passing by each other would be at right angles to the vector connecting the two particles!

But is there some reason that real forces should always be in the direction of the particles they connect (that is, attractive or repulsive)?

Edited to add: I guess I should limit the discussion to forces mediated by virtual particles, otherwise an oscillating (or just accelerating) charged particle can produce a wave which acts on another charged particle in a direction orthogonal to the wave's propagation.

Comment: Force is a classical concept which is meaningless with relation to particle interactions. One can't attach a force gauge to an electron, neither can one measure an electron's acceleration close to another strongly interacting particle. The action of a classical magnetic monopole on a charge particle can be analyzed, but such a thing does not exist in the real world, except in a fairly poor approximation as the end of a long magnetized rod.

Comment: @CuriousOne, you can always obtain classical behaviour in the limit. Consider the question to be about "an electrically charged large object" passing by "a magnetically charged large object".

Comment: So you're asking for examples of when Newtons third law doesn't apply? :)

Comment: @jabirali not at all. Do you imagine it doesn't apply to the hypothetical monopole case?

Comment: If you take into account that electromagnetic fields propagate at the speed of light, then two electrons moving past each other will not be repulsed by the location that the other electron *is*, but by the location that the other electron *was*. Thus the observed force is not along the line connecting the electrons at that moment. But I guess you still count that as a repulsive force then?

Comment: @jabirali yes, assume the particles are travelling slowly relative to the speed of light and don't take into account the small difference between where they "currently" are (if that means anything) and where they've been.

Comment: You mean a potential like discussed here? http://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0701232

Comment: @CuriousOne yes that is an interesting article, +1. My question is about whether such things can't exist in the real world.

Comment: That's not a question science can answer. The only question that can be answered is whether such a thing has been observed. So far, it has to the best of my knowledge not been observed, but there are still a few monopole searches out there. Whatever they may return, it won't be a classical monopole and I could only speculate if the classical limit of an elementary monopole has the field discussed in the article. Some folks who are much better at theory than me seem to think so.

Comment: @CuriousOne, I'm not asking whether such a thing has been observed (although I'd be interested if it had!), I'm asking whether there are theoretical reasons to believe that such a thing is not possible.

Comment: Theory can not tell you if something is possible or not. At most it can tell you if something fits into an existing theoretical framework. Do magnetic monopoles fit into a classical framework? Sure. You can plug ANY potential into classical physics and turn the cranks. Do elementary magnetic monopoles fit into the standard model of particle physics? Absolutely, or we wouldn't be searching for them.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12122/2451

Comment: @HughAllen please see [this quantitative discussion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/609085/254821) on *the assumption of the centrality of forces* which is required to obtain a theory of mechanics in which *the law of conservation of angular momentum* holds.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, we cannot rule out forces not directed along the line joining particles with current theory. As you point out, magnetic monopoles are a counterexample, and, as CuriousOne points out, magnetic monopoles both fit into a classical framework, are consistent with the Standard Model and are actively, experimentally sought.

Some historical comments on this question are in order though, I believe.

One reason that you might classically give (*i.e.* in Newtonian mechanics) for a "yes" answer to your question is that an assumption of acting of force along the line joining the two particles is needed, otherwise the system's angular momentum is not conserved. Consider two particles, equidistant from the origin and with equal and opposite forces on each other at right angles to the line joining them. The orbital angular momentum about the whole origin steadily and linearly increases with time! So in Newtonian, action-at-a-distance thinking, this is a problem. Hence, I believe Newton himself postulated that the force between particles is always along the line joining them. Notice that, contrary to some of the comments, this is *not* a breach of Newton's third law. A postulate of force along the line joining particles is something further to and independent from Newton's third law.

Another way of thinking about  this from a [Noether's Theorem standpoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) is that our proposed, spontaneous angular momentum-generating system above has physics that are *not* invariant with respect to a global rotation of our co-ordinate system. You need to choose a *preferred* direction to define the force direction in our example. So our system's description is *not rotationally invariant*, hence the breakdown of the law of conservation of angular momentum.

A flaw in all of the above (assumption of force along the line joining particles) as we now know is that the World is not just particles and "empty space" (in the sense of a void). There are *fields* too, and these are strongly believed to have an objective reality in modern physics (indeed I would say that "empty space" is *made* of ground state quantum fields). Physics is *local*. So in tallying up angular momentum, we need to take account of the momentum and angular momentum of *fields*. Thus, in the classical sense Newton's third law does not hold, but its abstraction and generalisation to the law of conservation of momentum most certainly does when we tally up the field contribution. Likewise for angular momentum.

Comment: Great answer. I am linking the directly related [quantitative discussion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/609085/254821) on the assumption of the centrality of forces which is required to obtain a theory of mechanics in which the law of conservation of angular momentum holds.